# update_post_meta doesn't work

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I've been drilling with codes for so long.

I was trying to create a metabox with a simple textare on it.

Been stuck for almost 10 hours tyring to solve this.

Still up until right now my meta box information won't save.

Here's my codes:

```
add_action("admin_init", "custom_product_metabox");

function custom_product_metabox(){
  add_meta_box("custom_product_metabox_01", "Product Description", "custom_product_metabox_field", "portfolio_page", "normal", "low");
}

function custom_product_metabox_field(){
    global $post;

    $data = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $val = isset($data['custom_product_input']) ? esc_attr($data['custom_product_input'][0]) : 'no value';

        wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );

        $text = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_product_input', true);

        echo '<textarea rows="5" cols="220" name="custom_product_input" id="custom_product_input" value="'.$val.'"></textarea>';
    }

add_action("save_post", "save_detail");

function save_detail( $post_id, $post, $update ){
    // global $post;

    if(defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE){
             return $post_id;
        }

        if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    update_post_meta($post_id, "custom_product_input", $_POST["custom_product_input"]);
}
```

I've been playing around with this and still have no luck on making my one and only textarea to save so I can pull up the data and use it on my frontend. I am using [bridge wordpress theme](https://themeforest.net/item/bridge-creative-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/7315054).

Anyone who can help me please? I really want to solve this.

Comment: Try debugging this step by step. Is `save_detail()` called? Is the first `if` false? Is the second `if` false? Is the third `if` false? Do the variables used in `update_post_meta()` contain what you believe they do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem could be that you dont show properly the value of the custom field, try this:

```
echo '<textarea rows="5" cols="220" name="custom_product_input" id="custom_product_input">' . $text . '</textarea>';
```

Comment: Some escaping in there would be nice, I guess ;)

Comment: I think escape html tags should be in the save_custom_field function.

Comment: You should sanitize in save function. You always have to escape when you print user input... What if I put </textarea> as that value? It will break HTML of that site. And of course I can put it in there...

Comment: mmm but sanitize dont remove all html tags?

Comment: No. Why should it?